# Yarn warning on docker build

Tags: docker, yarnpkg

Upon running `yarn install` inside my docker container it gives a warning about being without connection.
https://hub.docker.com/r/tavern/rpg-web/~/dockerfile/

`warning You don't appear to have an internet connection. Try the --offline flag to use the cache for registry queries.`

What could be causing this?

Comment: Same problem for me

Comment: If yarn is not installing the packages, you should try doing a network activity as a part of that command. Example: 'RUN ping -c1 google.com && yarn install'. It does the job

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since your Dockerfile has a line reading `RUN yarn` (i.e. not using yarn's offline options), yarn attempts to determine if the internet is likely to be available automatically without sending any packets.

#### How does yarn check online status?

This is done by enumerating the available network interfaces in the docker builder context using node's [`os.networkInterfaces()`](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/v0.17.4/src/util/network.js#L12), which is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces).

This in turn calls [`GetInterfaceAddresses`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v7.1.0/src/node_os.cc#L189) which is backed by libuv's [`uv_interface_addresses`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.10.1/src/unix/linux-core.c#L872). The libuv function only returns interfaces that have an IP address assigned and the `IFF_UP` and `IFF_RUNNING` flags set.

To see which addresses are actually being returned to Javascript code, you can temporarily add this line to your Dockerfile:

`RUN node -e 'const os = require("os"); const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces(); for (const interface in interfaces) {console.log(interface); const addrs = interfaces[interface]; for (const addr of addrs) {console.log(addr.address)}}'`

At least in my case this only returned the loopback address, which yarn explicitly ignores in [1](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/v0.17.4/src/util/network.js#L12):

`lo
127.0.0.1
::1`

But running `ifconfig` in the docker image showed an `eth0` interface as well. The `HWaddr` of this interface matches that of the `docker0` interface on the machine running the docker daemon. This suggests the builder context runs with the docker bridge network.

#### So what criteria is excluding the bridge network from libuv's list?

In my case, the docker network did not set `IFF_RUNNING`. This is not too surprising as the [Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/operstates.txt) says this field is for backward compatibility.

To verify this is the case in your instance you can use a slightly modified version of the sample program in [this document](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html), add this code after the first `printf()` call:

`printf("RUNNING: %s", (ifa->ifa_flags & IFF_RUNNING) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");`

#### Why isn't docker setting `IFF_RUNNING`?

Setting interface flags is a low-level operation that docker does not handle itself. Docker's libnetwork delegates to the netlink library [here](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/blob/master/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L1040), but netlink only [sets `IFF_UP`](https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink/blob/ffec63e1f1d04e356402671aff3f8da58b5dc585/link_linux.go#L134).

#### How can it be fixed?

The relevant moving parts to this issue are open source!

netlink was [changed](https://github.com/vishvananda/netlink/pull/165) to expose `IFF_RUNNING` for reading - it might be possible to enable libnetwork (and thus docker) to set that flag via a further change to netlink.

Alternately libuv might be extended following a [Github issue on the subject](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/158). Such a new API could eventually be used in node.js and yarn that would list interfaces regardless of assigned IP addresses and `IFF_RUNNING` state.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a possible explanation why this happens sometimes in the same container, and other times it's fine?